# How can I move cursor to end of text in ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor5

`ckeditor5`

when I used `editor.editing.view.focus()`, the cursor was at the beginning of the text, how can I move cursor to end of text?

Comment: Please provide more context informations. Would be helpful to fix your issue.

Answer (score 12):

To do that, set the selection in the [editor model](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#model):

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    writer.setSelection( writer.createPositionAt( editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' ) );
} );
```